# Managing third party javascript libraries with bundled jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a website globalization project, which involves (us the vendor) asking our clients to insert a script tag on their home/origin site. The script tag is necessary for helping our clients go global, and part of the solution embodies a UI that gets triggered based on certain end user criteria.

The UI is built through the help of jQuery, which we really can't expect our clients to insert on their pages, not to mention version mismatches will be hard to resolve. Therefore, our third party library downloads its own jQuery version, albeit namespaced differently to avoid any conflicts.

However, such a mechanism requires us to rename all instances of jQuery to something that will help us avoid name clashes with another jQuery instance (if present), and makes the our mangled jQuery (MY_Query in examples below) very hard to manage, let alone upgrade.

For example

```
jQuery = window.jQuery = window.$ = function( selector, context ) {
    // The jQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new jQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
}, 
.
.
.
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype = ...
```

becomes

```
MY_JQuery = window.MY_JQuery = window.MY_Q = function( selector, context ) {
    // The MY_JQuery object is actually just the init constructor 'enhanced'
    return new MY_JQuery.fn.init( selector, context );
},
.
.
.
MP_JQuery.fn = MP_JQuery.prototype = ...
```

In an ideal world, both us and the client would have a single version of jQuery on the site, and we both would use it to our advantage. But that would mean an upgrade of jQuery would require heavy testing on both sides (while the mangled jQuery version is contained) and that any plugin wanted would require the client to add appropriate script tags to their site, spurring a political debate between the two parties on what versions win.

So, can I manage our jQuery version (with plugins) on a client site without having to rename all instances of jQuery with something like MY_Query with the constraints mentioned above?

Comment: Why not link to the google code jquery libraries, you all would have the same version and never need to upgrade them, just a thought.

Comment: quite difficult to convince the client to do so. Plus, there could be legal reasons for the client to reject this proposal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not check to see if they have jQuery already included on the page and if not dynamically load it? If you know the base level jQuery needed you can check for that like this:

```
if( !jQuery || !jQuery.fn.jquery === "1.4.4"){
  var url = "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js";
  var script = document.createElement( 'script' );
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = url;
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

You'd probably want to improve the version detection to make sure that it doesn't have a version after 1.4.4, but I'm sure you could write the code for that yourself ;-)

==== Edit based on feedback

So you need to maintain multiple versions of jquery on the page. Have you tried something like this:

```
var original_jquery = $().noConflict();
original_jquery.getScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js");
var new_jquery = $().noConflict();
window.$ = original_jquery;
```

Then use the new_jquery as your version of jquery? I haven't tested this to see if it would work, but you might have some luck with it.

==== Final edit

As you mentioned, my javascript above wasn't exactly correct, so I tried out a few things in the console. And yes, you don't need to save the old version of jQuery because jQuery does that in the noConflict method. So just call getScript, then noConflict but saving to a new variable:

```
>> $.fn.jquery
"1.4.2"
>> $.getScript("http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js");
undefined
>> $.fn.jquery
"1.4.4"
>> var new_jquery = $.noConflict();
undefined
>> new_jquery.fn.jquery
"1.4.4"
>> $.fn.jquery
"1.4.2"
```

Comment: the different versions of jQuery use the same namespaces. Therefore, the above won't work when jQuery 1.3.2 is on the site and we want to download 1.4.4 and automatically, all references to jQuery now point to 1.4.4, while our client expects it to be 1.3.2

Comment: Is there some sort of common ground that you program to? Are you writing your code so that it will only work on jQuery 1.4.4?

Comment: The jQuery library in use by me is 1.3.2 and clients have varying versions

Comment: I was trying something very similar to what you have proposed in your edit, if that works I will accept the answer

Comment: The steps outlined above don't work, but the concept works. 

The first no_conflict() will create a null object [btw the syntax is $.noConflict()]. Simple call $.getScript("...") and assign to a variable (jQ_version) the new $. Perform a $.noConflict() and the original $ and jQuery objects have been restored, while preserving loaded jQ_version. 

Please update the answer based this comment and I will accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use [JQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). This sounds like it could help you.

Comment: I have certainly tried using jQuery.noConflict(), but that will simply release the previously set $ variable back to its original owner. All jQuery instances will still be affected by the new jQuery library downloaded